# How to display fixed number of entries from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 100+ entries, I want to display fixed number of entries from this table randomly.

I am using the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE active='1' AND id NOT IN 
(SELECT ad_id FROM Table1_logs WHERE uid='$username') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

`Table1` contain all the entries, `Table1_logs` contains the entries which have been utilized by users today.

Problem:

I need to pick `5` entries daily for each users and should not exceed that amount.
when a user utilizes one entry and it is saved in logs, query picks again `5` entries and it remains `5` all the time.

What I want to acheieve:

When a user utilizes one entry, it count should decrease. He should be able to see only `5` entries daily.

Comment: what's wrong with your query? error? wrong results?

Comment: @fuzzytree I have mentioned that it picks 5 entries, when one link is utilized it again picks next 5 randomly. I want to display 5 entries only. when one link is utlized it should decrease the count and so on, and make it zero when all 5 are utlizied .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a new field to table1 "utilizationCount" . When a link is utilized, you increase the value by one. And in the query, you should order by this field: " order by utilizationCount asc limit 5" .